# Is there a way to populate my combobox with values of column in a database

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

What I have at the moment doesn't work.

```
public List<DeparturePortInfo> departureportlist { get; set; }

public passagespage()
{
    db = new dbBoatDataContext();
    departureportlist = new List<DeparturePortInfo>();
    DataContext = this;
    DepCB.ItemsSource = departureportlist;
}
```

In XAML I don't know what to do.

I'm using LINQ to connect to SQL, so I have no `connectionString` in my code.

Anyway the CB doesn't populate, because I don't know how to specify the column to bind to. Can anybody please help?

Comment: You didn't add data to the `departureportlist`

Comment: Thanks Pavel, not quite sure i understand.  I'm quite new to coding, so please excuse if it's a stupid question.  I figured i'm adding the table(departureportlist) which has 5 columns and already has some data in it.  What am i still missing in this code?

I tried departureportlist.PortName but it didn't work.